# como puedo dejar abierto un acordeón con jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy haciendo un acordeón y quisiera saber como puedo dejar abierto uno de los titulos. Por ej detectores de potencia.

```js
$(".accordion-wrap").on("click", function(){   
      $(this).children().eq(1).slideToggle(300);  
      $(this).children().eq(0).toggleClass("accordion-no-bar");
      $(this).siblings().find(".accordion-header").removeClass("accordion-gold");
      $(this).siblings().find(".accordion-header i").removeClass("rotate-fa");
      $(this).find(".accordion-header").toggleClass("accordion-gold");
      $(this).find(".fa").toggleClass("rotate-fa");

      $(".accordion-wrap .accordion-text").not($(this).children().eq(1)).slideUp(300);
});
```

```css
/*ACORDEON*/
#categoria .cabecera_acorderon{
  background-color: #264a92;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;  
}
#categoria .cabecera_acorderon h2{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
}
#categoria .accordion-wrap{
  border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-right: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

#categoria .accordion-item{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  padding: 13px 15px 0 15px;
}

#categoria .accordion-header{
  transition: ease-in-out 100ms;
  font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #5d5d5d;
  font-weight: 500
}

#categoria .accordion-text{
  width: 100%; 
  display: none;
 }
#categoria .accordion-text .contenido ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0
}
#categoria .accordion-text .contenido ul li{
  padding: 7px 0;
}
#categoria .accordion-text .contenido ul .active{
  background-color: #dadbdf;
  color: #5d5d5d
}
#categoria .accordion-text .contenido ul li:hover{
  background-color: #dadbdf
}
#categoria .accordion-text .contenido ul li a{
  color: #5d5d5d;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin: 2px 15px;
}
#categoria .accordion-text .contenido ul li a span{
  color: #00aeef
}
#categoria .accordion-text .contenido ul li a:hover{
  text-decoration: none
}

#categoria .fa{
  transition: ease-in-out 300ms;
 }

#categoria .rotate-fa{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
 }


#categoria .accordion-header .fa{
  float: right;
  line-height: 22px;
}
#categoria .accordion-item:hover{
  background: #00abeb;
}
#categoria .accordion-gold{
  color: #fff;
}

#categoria .accordion-no-bar{
  border-bottom: 0;
  background: #00abeb;
  padding: 13px 15px 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="col-lg-12" id="categoria">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
     <div class="cabecera_acorderon">
      <h2>INSTRUMENTAL DE MEDICIÓN LASER</h2>
     </div>
              <div class="accordion-wrap">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <p class="accordion-header">Monitores<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-text">
                  <div class="contenido">
                   <ul>
                    <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> XLP12 <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP10-H <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP12-H <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-H <span>(33)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP25-H <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-H <span>(26)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP17-H-W <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-W <span>(28)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP50-W <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-VR <span>(8)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-VR <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> PRONTO-250 <span>(2)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UM-B <span>(2)</span></a></li>
                   </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>


             <div class="accordion-wrap">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <p class="accordion-header"> Detectores de energia <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-text">
                  <div class="contenido">
                   <ul>
                    <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> XLP12 <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP10-H <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP12-H <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-H <span>(33)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP25-H <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-H <span>(26)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP17-H-W <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-W <span>(28)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP50-W <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-VR <span>(8)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-VR <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> PRONTO-250 <span>(2)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UM-B <span>(2)</span></a></li>
                   </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>


              <div class="accordion-wrap">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <p class="accordion-header"> DETECTORES DE POTENCIA <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-text">
                  <div class="contenido">
                   <ul>
                    <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> XLP12 <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP10-H <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP12-H <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-H <span>(33)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP25-H <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-H <span>(26)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP17-H-W <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-W <span>(28)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP50-W <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-VR <span>(8)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-VR <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> PRONTO-250 <span>(2)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UM-B <span>(2)</span></a></li>
                   </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>
              <div class="accordion-wrap">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <p class="accordion-header"> SOLUCIONES DE ALTA POTENCIA <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-text">
                  <div class="contenido">
                   <ul>
                    <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> XLP12 <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP10-H <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP12-H <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-H <span>(33)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP25-H <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-H <span>(26)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP17-H-W <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-W <span>(28)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP50-W <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-VR <span>(8)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-VR <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> PRONTO-250 <span>(2)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UM-B <span>(2)</span></a></li>
                   </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>
              <div class="accordion-wrap">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <p class="accordion-header"> DETECTORES DE FOTOS <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-text">
                  <div class="contenido">
                   <ul>
                    <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> XLP12 <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP10-H <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP12-H <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-H <span>(33)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP25-H <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-H <span>(26)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP17-H-W <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-W <span>(28)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP50-W <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-VR <span>(8)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-VR <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> PRONTO-250 <span>(2)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UM-B <span>(2)</span></a></li>
                   </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>
              <div class="accordion-wrap">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <p class="accordion-header"> DETECTORES THz <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-text">
                  <div class="contenido">
                   <ul>
                    <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> XLP12 <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP10-H <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP12-H <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-H <span>(33)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP25-H <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-H <span>(26)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP17-H-W <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-W <span>(28)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP50-W <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-VR <span>(8)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-VR <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> PRONTO-250 <span>(2)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UM-B <span>(2)</span></a></li>
                   </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>
              <div class="accordion-wrap">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <p class="accordion-header"> PRODUCTOS ESPECIALES <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-text">
                  <div class="contenido">
                   <ul>
                    <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> XLP12 <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP10-H <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP12-H <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-H <span>(33)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP25-H <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-H <span>(26)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP17-H-W <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-W <span>(28)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP50-W <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-VR <span>(8)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-VR <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> PRONTO-250 <span>(2)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UM-B <span>(2)</span></a></li>
                   </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
             </div> 
              <div class="accordion-wrap">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <p class="accordion-header"> DIAGNÓSTICO DE LUZ <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-text">
                  <div class="contenido">
                   <ul>
                    <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> XLP12 <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP10-H <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP12-H <span>(9)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-H <span>(33)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP25-H <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-H <span>(26)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP17-H-W <span>(6)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-W <span>(28)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP50-W <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP19-VR <span>(8)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UP55-VR <span>(24)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> PRONTO-250 <span>(2)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> UM-B <span>(2)</span></a></li>
                   </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>                                                         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: solo uno de los títulos o todos los que se abren?

Comment: Solo uno necesito, osea la idea es que cuando uno ingrese a la pagina se encuentre con un titulo desplegado y mostrando los items que posee, en este caso seria detectores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añade esta linea despues de tu handler:

```
$(".accordion-wrap").eq(2).click();
```

Comment: Perfecto! anduvo de diez, Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te funciono, marca la respuesta como correcta